# SceneKit physics don't work properly in ARKit

Tags: ios, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I'm new to `ARKit` and I'm trying to make a relatively simple app where you create a "wall" and the user "throws" balls at it, and it bounces back.

I create the wall as a `SCNPlane` where the user is pointing the camera to like so:

```
private func createWall(withPosition position: SCNVector3) -> SCNNode {
    let wallGeometry = SCNPlane(width: 0.3, height: 0.3)
    wallGeometry.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
    wallGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.green.withAlphaComponent(0.7)

    let parentNode = SCNNode(geometry: wallGeometry)

    let (position, _) = cameraPosition()
    parentNode.position = position

    parentNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .static, shape: SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: wallGeometry, options: nil))
    parentNode.physicsBody?.isAffectedByGravity = false

    self.wall = parentNode

    return parentNode
}
```

I get the direction and position of camera with this function:
**`cameraPosition()`**:

```
func cameraPosition() -> (SCNVector3, SCNVector3) {
    guard let frame = sceneView.session.currentFrame else { return (SCNVector3(0, 0, -1), (SCNVector3(0, 0, 0))) }
    let matrix = SCNMatrix4(frame.camera.transform)
    let direction = SCNVector3(-matrix.m31, -matrix.m32, -matrix.m33)
    let location = SCNVector3(matrix.m41, matrix.m42, matrix.m43)
    return ((location + direction), direction)
}

// Helper function
func +(left: SCNVector3, right: SCNVector3) -> SCNVector3 {
    return SCNVector3(left.x + right.x, left.y + right.y, left.z + right.z)
}
```

I create instances of `Ball()` and throw them like this:

```
let (position, direction) = cameraPosition()

// throw ball
let ball = Ball()
ball.position = position //SCNVector3(0,0,0)
sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ball)

let impulseModifier = Float(10)
ball.physicsBody!.applyForce(SCNVector3(direction.x*impulseModifier, direction.y*impulseModifier, direction.z*impulseModifier), asImpulse: true)
```

The Ball class:

```
class Ball: SCNNode {
    override init() {
        super.init()

        let sphere = SCNSphere(radius: 0.05)
        sphere.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
        self.geometry = sphere

        self.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic, shape: SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: sphere, options: nil))        
    }
}
```

The problem is that many times, instead of the ball actually hitting the wall, it will just travel through it, as if the physics body does not function properly. I noticed that sometimes it will work better when I change the distance and angle between the camera and the wall, but the results are never consistent as far as I've tried.
I have also tried to change the wall position to: `SCNVector3(0, 0, -1)` to position it exactly 1 meter deep away from the world origin, and the results were somewhat better but still not consistent.

Where could the problem lay and why?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: @mike_t not yet unfortunately :/

Comment: This issue might be because of lack of continuous collision detection in Scenekit.

Answer (score 3):

Set your wall physics to be kinematic so that the ball can react with it.

- Static objects don't react with anything.
- Kinematic objects react with other objects but other objects don't affect them.
- Dynamic of course means it works in both directions.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is due to the ball being too small for the collision detection to work properly. Try setting **continuousCollisionDetectionThreshold** equal to half of the ball radius. In this case:

```
ball.physicsBody?.continuousCollisionDetectionThreshold = 0.025
```

Comment: I have a situation where I am not getting didBeginContact delegate method returned, I just tried this on my ball but it didn't help, any other suggestions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61315179/didbegincontact-delegate-method-not-firing-for-arkit-collision-detection?noredirect=1#comment108482013_61315179